# Setting Tab Index

Tags: c#, grid, tabindex

I have some values in Grid at Runtime.. Two Columns "Name" and "Value".. I made column[0] i.e Name
uneditable..So when I press tab I don't want tabindex on Column[0]..I want Tab to move  only on editable values.. Can Anyone Help!!!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set TabIndex for that column with a negative value as -1.

From this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.tabindex.aspx) on MSDN you have the following:

> You can remove a Web Server control from the tab order by setting
>   the TabIndex property to a negative
>   value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, negative values wont work on tab index, it makes error, if that's the case try positive number or zero for your tab index.

Thanks,